# How to stop the screen from flashing?

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina. I use a setup with Karabiner Elements and Hammerspoon, so I can switch between apps using shortcuts like `Caps-Lock+Letter`.

My caps-lock is configured to act as a 'Hyper' key when held down, meaning its the same as pressing `command + option + control + shift`.

However after Catalina upgrade, whenever I press `caps-lock + W`, the screen flashes.

It also happens when I press the keys individually, so `command + control + option + shift + W`, so I believe it is some new shortcut introduced in Catalina that does this.

However I can't seem to find what it is and how to disable it, could anybody please help?

The flash is the same as the flash you see when you go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio > Test Screen Flash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### WiFi Diagnostics Keyboard Shortcut in macOS Catalina

It looks like `cmd`+`ctrl`+`option`+`shift`+`w` triggers a WiFi Diagnostics session.

Browse to `/Private/var/tmp` and you'll see 300MB+ files titled `WiFiDiagnostics_YYYY-MM-DD_IP4-address_Mac OS X_MacModelName.tgz`

I can't find any official documentation on this, and I believe this is new for Catalina.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't yet have a solution to this problem. I can confirm that it manifests on my Catalina system as well. I wanted to add a comment but don't have enough reputation (any advice on how to better approach this is welcome).

Back to the issue at hand, on my 13" 2019 Retina MBA I can see the same problem. It is as if we're pressing a magic combo which seems to trigger a debugging session of sorts. The processes related to this, that I could find, are `footprint`, `lsregisterd`, `spindump`, `system_profiler`, `sysdiagnose` and `wifivelocity`. On this system, being a 2-core one, the CPUs go up to 100% and sit there while these processes run and do their thing. I had to resort to some shell magic to kill these to make it stop faster.

I have also asked a friend to press the combo on a 2016 MBP and I can confirm the system did the same thing, screen blinking, `footprint` process running, etc.

Does anyone have an idea on being able to reclaim this shortcut?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section.  This is for answers to the questions only.  If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  See [ask] for more info on how to ask a question. - From Review

Comment: Thanks @gm! It was a good instight, it indeed seems to run sysdiagnose, but its confusing, because the shortcut for that is `cmd+ctrl+option+shift+.` and not `w`